# How to fix classlist.toggle for my darkmode button

Tags: javascript, html, css, sveltekit

This code only wokrs the first time but after activating lightmode again the sun stops apreaing, how do I add back the bi-sun class only everyother click or when darkmode is not activated

```
function theme() {
        document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
        var element = document.getElementById('icon');
        element.classList.toggle('bi-moon-stars');
        element.classList.remove('bi-sun');
    }
```

Comment: Why are you are querying the DOM when you are using Svelte?

Comment: is there something else i should be doing... I'm not experience in svelte

Comment: Classes should be set using the [`class:`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-class-name) directive or the attribute. You should do [the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial) if you do not know how Svelte is supposed to be used.

Comment: I have tried alot of things but still cant get it to work, do you think you could give me something to go off of the documentation didn't help.

Comment: My comments have nothing to do with the logic of your question. I am just telling you that you are using Svelte the wrong way. Your logic is probably faulty regardless of how you apply the classes.

Comment: You always remove `bi-sun` how do you expect it to ever appear again?

Comment: Also, dark modes should have three states: Automatic (based on system), light, dark.

Comment: yeah i realize thats the problem but I don't know how to remove bi-sun then re add it....

Comment: and my darkmode does already have a automatic I just didn't add it in the code on stack overflow

Comment: What I mean is that "automatic" should also be selectable, not just the default the site opens with. (Go to the theme settings of StackOverflow for an example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working

```
function theme() {
        document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
        var element = document.getElementById('icon');
        if (document.body.classList.contains('dark')) {
            element.classList.add('bi-sun');
            element.classList.remove('bi-moon-stars');
        } else {
            element.classList.remove('bi-sun');
            element.classList.add('bi-moon-stars');
        }
    }
```